# Как перенести int, double, char в char const*?

Tags: c++, массивы, char

Как перенести int, double, char в char const* ?

Вот есть у меня клас телефон, у него есть свои характеристики. Мне говорят: "Сделай функцию, что будете возвращать все характеристики телефона в одной строке (char*).

Внимание, вопрос: "Как?".

Comment: Они явно подразумевают перенести не в `char const *`, а в буффер, на который указывает этот указатель (буфер наверное придется выделить).

Comment: Ещё могут иметь ввиду сериализации данных, типа json или yaml. Уточните у тех "кто говорит", что они хотят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа этого не подходит?

```
struct Phone
{
    char model[40];
    double price;
    int buttons;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Phone p;
    strcpy(p.model,"Nokia");
    p.price = 25.67;
    p.buttons = 20;

    char a[100];
    sprintf(a,"Phone %s with %d buttons for %.02lf dollars",
            p.model, p.buttons, p.price);

    cout << a << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю вариант к варианту, который предложил @Harry
Используя класс [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/), можно сделать так

```
#include <sstream>

struct Phone
{
    char model[40];
    double price;
    int buttons;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Phone p;
    strcpy_s(p.model, "Nokia");
    p.price = 25.67;
    p.buttons = 20;

    std::ostringstream stringStream;
    stringStream << p.model << p.price << p.buttons;
    std::string s = stringStream.str();
    const char* ps = s.c_str();     

    std::cout << ps << std::endl;
}
```

Плюс этого подхода в том что нет необходимости в предварительном расчете длины строки.

Comment: Я в другом вопросе на эту тему спрашивал автора - он сказал, что `string` использовать запрещено условиями игры :(